# R httr post-authentication download works in interactive mode but fails in function

Tags: r, cookies, https, web-scraping, httr

the code below works fine in interactive mode but fails when used in a function. it's pretty simply two authentications `POST` commands followed by the data download.  my goal is to get this working inside a function, not just in interactive mode.

this question is sort of a sequel to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204503/how-to-use-r-to-download-a-zipped-file-from-a-ssl-page-that-requires-cookies)..  icpsr recently updated their website.  the minimal reproducible example below requires a free account, available at

https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/rpxlogin?path=ICPSR&request_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwww.icpsr.umich.edu%2ficpsrweb%2findex.jsp

i tried adding `Sys.sleep(1)` and various `httr::GET`/`httr::POST` calls but nothing worked.

```
my_download <-
    function( your_email , your_password ){

        values <-
            list(
                agree = "yes",
                path = "ICPSR" ,
                study = "21600" ,
                ds = "" ,
                bundle = "rdata",
                dups = "yes",
                email=your_email,
                password=your_password
            )


        httr::POST("https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/cgi-bin/terms", body = values)
        httr::POST("https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/rpxlogin", body = values)

        tf <- tempfile()
        httr::GET( 
            "https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/cgi-bin/bob/zipcart2" , 
            query = values , 
            httr::write_disk( tf , overwrite = TRUE ) , 
            httr::progress()
        )

    }

# fails 
my_download( "email@address.com" , "some_password" )

# stepping through works
debug( my_download )
my_download( "email@address.com" , "some_password" )
```

**EDIT** the failure simply downloads this page as if not logged in (and not the dataset), so it's losing the authentication for some reason.  if you are logged in to icpsr, use private browsing to see the page--

https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/cgi-bin/bob/zipcart2?study=21600&ds=1&bundle=rdata&path=ICPSR

thanks!

Comment: so where / how exactly does it fail when used via the function?

Comment: @RolandASc sorry for not including that.  see edit..thank you

Comment: https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/robots.txt suggests this activity is not authorized (and `robots.txt` is currently a bona fide technical control upheld in — at least U.S. — civil courts). Unless one has written permission to automate access, it's not a good idea to pursue this.

Comment: I suggest ignoring @hrbrmstr's hand-wringing about robots.txt. At least it is not clear that a) your script qualifies as a "robot", or b) that respecting restrictions specified in robots.txt is necessarily a good idea. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard for relatively unbiased information on this issue.

Comment: For me running the function a second time works. So it's not about running it line-by-line, but rather whether it's been run before. In practical terms: just run it twice.

Comment: @Ista bizarro.  yes, running the three `POST` and `GET` commands twice triggers the download within the function.  happy to award the bounty if you want to make that an answer.  thanks very much!

Comment: Nice job encouraging unethical and (depending on the jurisdiction) criminal actions, @Ista

Comment: Nice job trying to derail this question with irrelevant opinions @hrbrmstr. If you want to talk about legal issues please take it over to https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AnthonyDamico I'm going to look into it a bit more to see if I can actually understand what is happening before writing up an answer. It will a while before I have time to do that, hopefully someone else will beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing can happen because the state (such as cookies) the `httr` package stores in the `handle` for each URL (see `?handle`).

In this particular case it remains unclear what exactly make it work, but one strategy is to include a `GET` request to `https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/cgi-bin/bob/` prior to authenticating and requesting the data. For example,

```
my_download <-
    function( your_email , your_password ){
        ## for some reason this is required ...
        httr::GET("https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/cgi-bin/bob/")
        values <-
            list(
                agree = "yes",
                path = "ICPSR" ,
                study = "21600" ,
                ds = "" ,
                bundle = "rdata",
                dups = "yes",
                email=your_email,
                password=your_password
            )
        httr::POST("https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/rpxlogin", body = values)
        httr::POST("https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/cgi-bin/terms", body = values)
        tf <- tempfile()
        httr::GET( 
            "https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/cgi-bin/bob/zipcart2" , 
            query = values , 
            httr::write_disk( tf , overwrite = TRUE ) , 
            httr::progress()
        )
    }
```

appears to work correctly, though it remains unclear what the `GET` request to https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/cgi-bin/bob/` does exactly or why it is needed.