# How to login and then download a file from aspx web pages with R

Tags: asp.net, r, download, rcurl, httr

I'm trying to automate the download of the *Panel Study of Income Dynamics* files available on [this web page](http://simba.isr.umich.edu/Zips/ZipMain.aspx) using R.  Clicking on any of those files takes the user through to [this login/authentication page](http://simba.isr.umich.edu/u/Login.aspx).  After authentication, it's easy to download the files with your web browser.  Unfortunately, the `httr` code below does not appear to be maintaining the authentication.  I have tried inspecting the `Headers` in Chrome for the Login.aspx page ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213194/use-rcurl-to-bypass-disclaimer-page-then-do-the-web-scrapping)), but it doesn't appear to maintain the authentication even when I believe I'm passing in all the correct values.  I don't care if it's done with `httr` or `RCurl` or something else, I'd just like something that works inside R so I don't need to have users of this script have to download the files manually or with some completely separate program.  One of my attempts at this is below, but it doesn't work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!! :D

```
require(httr)

values <- 
    list( 
        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$Login1$UserName" = "you@email.com" , 
        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$Login1$Password" = "somepassword" ,
        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$Login1$LoginButton" = "Log In" ,
        "_LASTFOCUS" = "" ,
        "_EVENTTARGET" = "" ,
        "_EVENTARGUMENT" = "" 
    )

POST( "http://simba.isr.umich.edu/u/Login.aspx?redir=http%3a%2f%2fsimba.isr.umich.edu%2fZips%2fZipMain.aspx" , body = values )

resp <- GET( "http://simba.isr.umich.edu/Zips/GetFile.aspx" , query = list( file = "1053" ) )
```

Comment: You have to save the cookie after authentication and pass that with every further calls - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15451157/564164

Comment: @daroczig thanks.. i actually tried replicating that one yesterday, it did not work. :(  might anything else be going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beside storing the cookie after authentication (see my above comment) there was another problematic point in your solution: the ASP.net site sets a `VIEWSTATE` key-value pair in the cookie which is to be reserved in your queries - if you check, you could not even login in your example (the result of the `POST` command holds info about how to login, just check it out).

**An outline of a possible solution:**

1. Load `RCurl` package:

   ```
   > library(RCurl)
   ```
2. Set some handy `curl` options:

   ```
   > curl = getCurlHandle()
   > curlSetOpt(cookiejar = 'cookies.txt', followlocation = TRUE, autoreferer = TRUE, curl = curl)
   ```
3. Load the page for the first time to capture `VIEWSTATE`:

   ```
   > html <- getURL('http://simba.isr.umich.edu/u/Login.aspx', curl = curl)
   ```
4. Extract `VIEWSTATE` with a regular expression or any other tool:

   ```
   > viewstate <- as.character(sub('.*id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html))
   ```
5. Set the parameters as your username, password *and the `VIEWSTATE`*:

   ```
   > params <- list(
       'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$Login1$UserName'    = '<USERNAME>',
       'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$Login1$Password'    = '<PASSWORD>',
       'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$Login1$LoginButton' = 'Log In',
       '__VIEWSTATE'                                  = viewstate
       )
   ```
6. Log in at last:

   ```
   > html = postForm('http://simba.isr.umich.edu/u/Login.aspx', .params = params, curl = curl)
   ```

   Congrats, now you are logged in and `curl` holds the cookie verifying that!
7. Verify if you are logged in:

   ```
   > grepl('Logout', html)
   [1] TRUE
   ```
8. So you can go ahead and download any file - just be sure to pass `curl = curl` in all your queries.

Comment: yes!!!!!!!  that worked.  thank you!! :)  here are the two final lines to get what i wanted:  `file <- getBinaryURL("http://simba.isr.umich.edu/Zips/GetFile.aspx?file=1053", curl=curl)` and
`writeBin( file , "c:/temp/thefile.zip" )`

Comment: @daroczig  I have a similar query with a different .NET site.  Please let me know if you would like me to open a new thread.

Comment: @daroczig      Opened a new thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372987/login-to-net-site-using-r