# How to login and then extract table from html/aspx web pages with R

Tags: html, asp.net, r

My attempt is to extract a table from [this website](http://www.sxcoal.com/coal/3478186/articlenew.html).

The web is in Chinese, but basically, you can type your log-in details within those boxes lying above the big blue button in the middle of the web page. After logged-in, the table will appear in the middle of the page. NOTE: in /articlenew.html, only USERNAME and PASSWORD are required for log-in. Nothing else.

After authentication, the headers of the webs are shown as below:

```
Request URL:http://www.sxcoal.com/user/login.aspx
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en,en-GB;q=0.8,zh;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:39
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:the_cookies
Host:www.sxcoal.com
Origin:http://www.sxcoal.com
Referer:http://www.sxcoal.com/coal/3478186/articlenew.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
username:myusername
password:mypassword
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:167
Content-Type:text/html; charset=gb2312
Date:Thu, 14 Nov 2013 01:06:00 GMT
Location:http://www.sxcoal.com/coal/3478186/articlenew.html
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Set-Cookie:s_info=zhuhaiqinfa|15816; domain=sxcoal.com; path=/
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

I have tried to use the method shown by [Gergely Daróczi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853204/how-to-login-and-then-download-a-file-from-aspx-web-pages-with-r). However, R couldn't log-in for some reasons. My guess is that /login.aspx (http:[DELETE]//www.[DELETE]sxcoal.[DELETE]com/user/login.[DELETE]aspx
)[sorry I haven't got enough 'reputation' to post more links.] nested in the /articlenew.html actually requires more things than just a username and a corresponding password. I put the headers of the /login.aspx at the end of the question.

Here is the code I used,

```
library(RCurl)
mycurl <- getCurlHandle()
agent <- "Mozilla/5.0"
curlSetOpt(cookiejar = "", followlocation = TRUE, useragent = agent, autoreferer = TRUE, curl = mycurl)
html <- getURL('http://www.sxcoal.com/user/login.aspx', curl = mycurl) 
viewstate <- as.character(sub('.*id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html))  
eventvalidation <- as.character(sub('.*id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html))  
##checkcode <- ??????????????? ## can't define it as it changes
params <- list( 
        "txtuser"     = "myusername", 
        "txtpass"     = "mypassword",
        "__VIEWSTATE" = viewstate,
        "__EVENTVALIDATION" = eventvalidation,
        "CheckCode"   =  checkcode, 
        "Button2"     =  ""
        )
html <- postForm('http://www.sxcoal.com/user/login.aspx', .params = params, curl = mycurl)
```

The `CheckCode` is a validation code shown by a pic(http://www.sxcoal.com/CheckCode/CheckCode.aspx). Unlike the `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION`, the `CheckCode` changes every time when you refresh the page. 
And there is something every complicated as I don't know anything about website coding. It seems to me that the log-in details required by /login.aspx nested within /articlenew.html differ from those required by /login.aspx itself. Are there any methods that can fix the log-in details required by the web such that I don't need to deal with the validation code shown by a random picture? If not, can anyone know how I can take care of the validation picture?

Thanks in advance.

```
Request URL:http://www.sxcoal.com/user/login.aspx
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en,en-GB;q=0.8,zh;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:234
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:the_cookies
Host:www.sxcoal.com
Origin:http://www.sxcoal.com
Referer:http://www.sxcoal.com/user/login.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)                 Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
__VIEWSTATE:whatever_it_is
txtuser:myusername
txtpass:mypassword
CheckCode:04854
Button2:
__EVENTVALIDATION:whatever_it_it_2
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:170
Content-Type:text/html; charset=gb2312
Date:Thu, 14 Nov 2013 01:09:57 GMT
Location:http://www.sxcoal.com/?aspxerrorpath=/user/login.aspx
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```