# httr/RCurl: Login to sitecore [r]

Tags: javascript, r, sitecore

Trying to login into a sitecore site with R to fetch html tables. 
Part one, login did succeed after adding the following to the code.

```
EVENTVALIDATION <- as.character(sub('.*id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html))
```

Using the code example from: [How to login and then download a file from aspx web pages with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853204/how-to-login-and-then-download-a-file-from-aspx-web-pages-with-r)
Did try other possibilities but this looks most promising)

Is it just me having problems 'deciphering' the tags structure, or are there more grave errors in this approach

```
library(RCurl)
```

Set some handy curl options:

```
username = 'YourUser'
password = "YourPass"
url="http://formular.sinusenergi.dk/sitecore/login"
url2="http://formular.sinusenergi.dk/viewforms.aspx"
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar = 'cookies.txt', followlocation = TRUE, autoreferer = TRUE, curl = curl)
 ##Load the page for the first time to capture VIEWSTATE:

html <- getURL(url, curl = curl)
 ## Extract VIEWSTATE with a regular expression or any other tool:

viewstate <- as.character(sub('.*id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html))
EVENTVALIDATION <- as.character(sub('.*id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="([0-9a-zA-Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html))
```

Set the parameters as your username, password, VIEWSTATE, EVENTVALIDATION :

```
params <- list(
'Login$UserName'    = username,
'Login$Password'    = password,
'Login$Login' = 'Login',
'__VIEWSTATE'                                  = viewstate,
**"__EVENTVALIDATION" = EVENTVALIDATION**
```

)

Log in at last:

```
html = postForm(url, .params = params, curl = curl)
```

So now I do get logged in, but grepl('Logout', html) still returns false.

So now I can get to URL2 but haven't figure out how to 'trigger. the product selector, see code below.

This dos not work:

```
 params2 <- list(
'ddlProducts'    = '83d16692-63e0-4e9c-9720-0108cfd4fd05',

'__VIEWSTATE'                                  = viewstate,
"__EVENTVALIDATION" = EVENTVALIDATION
)
##Verify if you are logged in:
```

html = postForm(url2, .params = params2, curl = curl)
Returns the 'product selector code, but does not trigger, the same.

Thanks

Excerpt from site code:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->                
                <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1"><title>

</title></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/viewforms.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTQxMzE0MzQyMw8WAh4TVmFsaWRhdGVSZXF1ZXN0TW9kZQIBFgICAxBkZBYEAgEPZBYEAgEPEA8WBh4ORGF0YVZhbHVlRmllbGQFA0tleR4NRGF0YVRleHRGaWVsZAUFVmFsdWUeC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZ2QQFQgMVmFsZyBwcm9kdWt0ClNQQVIgc3Ryb20WRXJodmVydiBWQVJJQUJFTCBzdHJvbQpTUE9UIHN0cm9tEkVyaHZlcnYgU1BPVCBzdHJvbQ5WQVJJQUJFTCBzdHJvbQpGQVNUIHN0cm9tEkVyaHZlcnYgRkFTVCBzdHJvbRUIAi0xJDgzZDE2NjkyLTYzZTAtNGU5Yy05NzIwLTAxMDhjZmQ0ZmQwNSRkYTdhZmNhOS1iZWVmLTQ3NDgtODhhNC0wNWQ1MTQ4NDBmZGMkYjg0ZjFiNjMtMDVkZi00MjFjLWFlNGQtMTdjYWZkY2ZmZjc0JGNhNmYxYmQwLTBlYjEtNDExOC1hYmY4LTdlZmFmYTRmNTI2YyQ2NTY2YzgyZS1mNjcyLTQwZGYtOGJkYS1hYjAzOTI3YzdiOGQkN2E3YTVmY2ItMDFkNi00Mzg1LTgwZDUtZjY4MTY5ZmI2NGJmJGY5N2FmNWI1LTAxZDYtNGU4NC1iZjUwLWZhZDU1ZTJmZDU4NxQrAwhnZ2dnZ2dnZxYBZmQCAw88KwARAQwUKwAAZAIDDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZBgBBQ5ndlByb2R1Y3RzRm9ybQ9nZApFHGp6DkfeGiiy/DYgq3lHp9Aq7IMgedEE3Ce3QI0m" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">



<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION"     value="/wEdAAl0n//hvd...A==" />
    </div>
            <div>
                <div id="pForm">

                    <select name="ddlProducts" id="ddlProducts">
        <option selected="selected" value="-1">Valg produkt</option>
        <option value="83d16692-63e0-4e9c-9720-0108cfd4fd05">SPAR strom</option>
        <option value="da7afca9-beef-4748-88a4-05d514840fdc">Erhverv VARIABEL strom</option>
        <option value="b84f1b63-05df-421c-ae4d-17cafdcfff74">SPOT strom</option>
        <option value="ca6f1bd0-0eb1-4118-abf8-7efafa4f526c">Erhverv SPOT strom</option>
        <option value="6566c82e-f672-40df-8bda-ab03927c7b8d">VARIABEL strom</option>
        <option value="7a7a5fcb-01d6-4385-80d5-f68169fb64bf">FAST strom</option>
        <option value="f97af5b5-01d6-4e84-bf50-fad55e2fd587">Erhverv FAST strom</option>
    </select>
                    <div>
    </div>
                    <span id="lbResult"></span>                
</div>                
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Solved the last part:
Needed to include: __EVENTTARGET' and the choice for the eventarget variable.
Så the final 'params' list have the following structure.

```
'__VIEWSTATE'                                  = viewstate,
'__EVENTVALIDATION' = EVENTVALIDATION,
'__EVENTTARGET' =  "ddlProducts",
'ddlProducts'    = x[1]
```

Comment: It's still very young, but you might find rvest, https://github.com/hadley/rvest, easier for this sort of task.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, have installed and will try to use the package for this task.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to automate here and why? Are trying to run some UI tests or just get some data out?

Comment: Trying to get data out. The tables are first shown when a product is selected from a dropdown list. And my objective is to automate the task of fetching and storing the data on these pages.

Answer (score 0):

Automating the admin screens of the CMS is not an easy task, and unless it is something but the very rudimentary it is likely to break in the future as content changes.

You should look into the [Sitecore Item Web API](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20Item%20Web%20API.aspx) instead, which will allow you to access and manipulate Sitecore conent items via a REST API returning data in JSON format.  You can also apply security to restrict access and the calls can be made either from client side or from server side C# code.

- [Sitecore Item Web API Client Library](http://sitecorecreative.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/sitecore-web-api-client-library/)
- [Content-As-A-Service and the Sitecore Item Web API](http://sitecorestrategy.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/content-as-service-and-sitecore-item.html)
- [SitecoreJunkie: Sitecore Item Web API](http://sitecorejunkie.com/category/sitecore-item-web-api/)

There is also a great walkthrough by [Mike Reynolds in this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBZjWZnbsQU).

Example usage:

```cs
var query = new SitecoreExpressionQuery(SitecoreQueryType.Read);
query.Query = "/sitecore/content/Home/*";

var credentials = new SitecoreCredentials();
credentials.UserName = "extranet\\foo";
credentials.Password = "bar";
credentials.EncryptHeaders = true;

var context = new AuthenticatedSitecoreDataContext("host", credentials);

ISitecoreWebResponse response = context.GetResponse(query);     
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    foreach (WebApiItem item in response.Result.Items)
    {
        // the Key property of the KeyValuePair holds the field id
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, WebApiField> field in item.Fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("fieldid: " + field.Key);
            Console.WriteLine("fieldname: " + field.Value.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("fieldtype: " + field.Value.Type);
            Console.WriteLine("fieldvalue: " + field.Value.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Jammykam. My problem is that I'm not familiar with .Net (or the sitecore API), so to go that way is not presently a possibility

Comment: Since the response is in JSON you can consume it from any language, one of the linked examples makes a call from Javascript (sorry, my bad, just saw this tag so would have been better to given that example). You don't need to be familiar with the Sitecore API but you will need to understand some Sitecore concepts to consume the data.